# how do I determine which objects use a specific table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to find/create the sql that will return any/all objects related to a specific table, be it another table or procedure, whatever is using the table in question. Is there a specific table I should be looking for or any specific parameters I should be using? I am a novice, I am using Microsoft SQL Server Management studio 2008 R2
Thanks in advance for any help/assistance offered.

Comment: You can also right click the object you wish on the SQL Management Studio and then click View Dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the sp_depends system stored procedure.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189487.aspx

Example: you have a table USERS and wish to see what objects you should check before making changes:

```
EXEC sys.sp_depends 'USERS'
```

If you happen to own the Red-Gate dependency tracker, this takes a more visual approach which is easy to check the impact.

Answer (score 0):

Check out sys.dm_sql_referencing_entities. Use it like so:

```
select * from sys.dm_sql_referencing_entities('schema.objectName', 'object')
```